# while loop - increments value

Tags: python-3.4

here is code below,

```
spam = 0  

while spam < 5:                   
    print('Hello, world.')

    spam = spam + 1
```

Questions:

So does spam = spam + 1 , mean how much the increment would increase by. since there is a + 1 here, it would increase by 1 ?

if so does this while loop increase by 1 until the 5th increment value, which the 5th increment value would lead to a False value of the condition, is description below correct ?

## while spam is less than 5, it will print hello world up to the 4th increment value

```
 # 0 < 5 = true = prints hello world
 # 1 < 5 = true = prints hello world
 # 2 < 5 = true = prints hello world
 # 3 < 5 = true = prints hello world
 # 4 < 5 = true = prints hello world
 # 5 < 5 = fals = no printing of hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes. Since that you start the spam with 0. 0-4 values will be the true statement on your condition. And it will execute by 5.